# How to get Not expression predicate from expression Predicate?

Tags: .net, expression-trees

There is domain-specific class:

```
public class Account : IEntity
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
}
```

and some predicate for fetching accounts from datasource:

```
Expression<Func<Account, bool>> predicate = a => a.IsActive == false && a.ExpirationDate < DateTime.Now;

List<Account> lst = new List<Account>();
lst.AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
```

How can i generate not_predicate from my predicate? Where not_predicate is:

```
!(a.IsActive == false && a.ExpirationDate < DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might need slights tweaks (I'm not at a PC) - but something like:

```
var not = Expression.Lambda<Func<Account,bool>>(
    Expression.Not(predicate.Body), predicate.Parameters);
```